# Are there software enabling translation when seeing a video?

Tags: video, software-rec, video-editing, translation

I have `videos` , `flv` format, the `language` spoken is `american-english` and I don't understand most of what is said. So I need that there is a translation below the screen when I see the video. So are there software which enable translation from american-english to french ? The best approach is translation from any language to the french language because my second language is french.

Comment: (software to translate speech into text and then into another language with high accuracy is very hard to write) the only option i see is to check if those "videos" have been subtitled in french and if the subtitles are available online; even if they are you still might have sync problems between the subtitles and the "video". if your written english is alright, why wouldn't english subtitles help?

Comment: Keep in mind that translating text is hard, imagine translating voice...